# How to convert int to const int to assign array size on stack?

Tags: c++, stack, integer, constants

I am trying to allocate a **fixed size on stack to an integer array**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n1 = 10;
    const int N = const_cast<const int&>(n1);
    //const int N = 10;
    cout<<" N="<<N<<endl;
    int foo[N];
    return 0;
}
```

However, this gives an error on the last line where I am using `N` to define a fixed
`error C2057: expected constant expression`.

However, if I define `N` as `const int N = 10`, the code compiles just fine. 
How should I typecast `n1` to trat it as a `const int`?

**I tried :** `const int N = const_cast<const int>(n1)` but that gives error.

**EDIT    :** I am using MS VC++ 2008 to compile this... with g++ it compiles fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How should I typecast `n1` to treat it as a `const int`?

You cannot, not for this purpose.

The size of the array must be what is called an *Integral Constant Expression* (ICE).  The value must be computable at compile-time.  A `const int` (or other const-qualified integer-type object) can be used in an Integral Constant Expression only if it is itself initialized with an Integral Constant Expression.

A non-const object (like `n1`) cannot appear anywhere in an Integral Constant Expression.

Have you considered using `std::vector<int>`?

[Note--The cast is entirely unnecessary. Both of the following are both exactly the same:

```
const int N = n1;
const int N = const_cast<const int&>(n1);
```

--End Note]

Comment: Just to add one more detail: gcc compiles it as an extension -- in fact, it allows other expressions that aren't even as close to conforming, like `int x(int a) { int b[a]; }`

Comment: Ah, thank you, @JerryCoffin.  I did not see the edit when I posted.

Comment: Instead of `const int` we could go for `constexpr int`, that way compiler will make sure that the value is ICE during assignment, instead of when you're trying to allocate an array.

Answer (score 4):

Only fixed-size arrays can be allocated that way. Either allocate memory dynamically (`int* foo = new int[N];`) and delete it when you're done, or (preferably) use `std::vector<int>` instead.

(Edit: [GCC accepts that as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), but it's not part of the C++ standard.)