# Testing template based class with const template parameter which has to be varied

Tags: c++, templates, testing, constants, const-cast

I am developing a template based library to support fixed point integers and I came up with this class and now I have to test it for various values of `INT_BITS` and `FRAC_BITS`. but since they are `const` (and they have to be so for a reason), I am unable to initialize objects with variable `INT_BITS` in a loop and hence it is making testing this library very difficult.

```
template<int INT_BITS, int FRAC_BITS>
struct fp_int
{
     public:
            static const int BIT_LENGTH = INT_BITS + FRAC_BITS;
            static const int FRAC_BITS_LENGTH = FRAC_BITS;
     private:
            // Value of the Fixed Point Integer 
            ValueType stored_val;
};
```

I tried a lot of tricks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583076/c-c-changing-the-value-of-a-const) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006161/changing-the-value-of-const-variable-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596650/how-to-convert-int-to-const-int-to-assign-array-size-on-stack). I tried using a `std::vector` of `const int` and `const_cast` but nothing seems to work.

I was wondering that that how do you test such libraries where the template parameter is a const for a large test values ?

Comment: Another option would be to write a program that outputs another C++ program that creates the object for various values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate a for loop using template meta programming.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int ValueType;

template<int INT_BITS, int FRAC_BITS>
struct fp_int
{
   public:
      static const int BIT_LENGTH = INT_BITS + FRAC_BITS;
      static const int FRAC_BITS_LENGTH = FRAC_BITS;
   private:
      // Value of the Fixed Point Integer 
      ValueType stored_val = 0;
};

template <unsigned int N> struct ForLoop
{
   static void testFpInt()
   {
      std::cout << "Testing fp_int<" << N << ", 2>\n";
      fp_int<N, 2> x;
      // Use x

      // Call the next level
      ForLoop<N-1>::testFpInt();
   }
};

// Terminating struct.
template <> struct ForLoop<0>
{
   static void testFpInt()
   {
      std::cout << "Testing fp_int<" << 0 << ", 2>\n";
      fp_int<0, 2> x;
      // Use x
   }
};

int main()
{
   ForLoop<10>::testFpInt();
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Testing fp_int<10, 2>
Testing fp_int<9, 2>
Testing fp_int<8, 2>
Testing fp_int<7, 2>
Testing fp_int<6, 2>
Testing fp_int<5, 2>
Testing fp_int<4, 2>
Testing fp_int<3, 2>
Testing fp_int<2, 2>
Testing fp_int<1, 2>
Testing fp_int<0, 2>
```

You can find more information on the web by searching for "for loop using template metaprogramming".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! if I am correct I need to write two terminating cases if I make a loop to vary both the `INT_BITS` and `FRAC_BITS` ?